# Is there a way to pull out image view from its' container a little bit in Android?

Tags: android, layout, imageview, android-linearlayout, margin

I want to create a layout based on the following image,

[image]

as it is evidence I have a CardView that I show it with red lines and the card view is in a LinearLayout and I have an image in the card view in which I want to show a little bit of it in a linear layout.

I use the following code to create the layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grayBack"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities_v2.customer_steps.CustomerStepOne">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/editText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp"

                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_100sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/_50sdp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_10sdp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="236dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_150sdp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_illustration_02" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/editText"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background_blue"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/_150sdp"

        android:textSize="@dimen/_14ssp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When u add an imageview inside of an cardview, that cardview becomes a parent for that imageview.

Comment: @PrajwalW yes I know, I want to know is there any way to achieve this layout without going into much customization?

Comment: Create an outer linearlayout that will be a parent of cardview and linearlayot and in that outerlayout add this image view.

Comment: @PrajwalW I think with the solution you mentioned, the outer layout should be relative layout or constraint layout, I handle the situation by using background for now. I think it is the simplest solution.

Comment: aah yes u can use relative or else constraint will also be good.